Is 3 ohm resistance value of a PCB fuse reasonable?
There is a PCB fuse on a board that I try to repair. It is manufactured by Schurter marked as MSF125 100 mA. According to the datasheet ratings are as follows:

Rated Current [A]  = 0.1
Rated Voltage [VAC] = 125
Rated Voltage [VDC] = 125
Voltage Drop 1.0 In max. [mV] = 1000
Voltage Drop 1.0 In typ. [mV] = 690
Power Dissipation 1.0 In max. [mW] = 100

I measure it's resistance as 3 Ω and I am not sure if it is OK or not?

kemal - Hi, Just to be clear, are you measuring 3 Ω with power off (e.g. using a DMM)? In this case, how accurate do you believe that DMM measurement to be e.g. did you account for lead resistance? Or are you calculating 3 Ω by measuring the Vdrop & I values with the circuit live? And in that case, what were the values, please? TY

Hi Sam. I measured it with my DMM. I know it is not accurate but I believe it is not fully false also. DMM's lead resistance is 0,2 Ohm , What I read from the DMM's display is actually 3,2 Ohm..

Yes, that's perfectly normal for such a low-current fuse. They need to drop voltage to self-heat enough to melt the metal fuse element.
The voltage drop is nonlinear with current due to the self-heating, but if you calculate the resistance from the voltage drop it's typically 6.9Ω at 100mA. It will be less when the element is cold. Around half that (3Ω) seems quite reasonable to me.

The maximum voltage drop at the rated current (In) is 1.0V, with a typical value of 0.69V. Using Ohm's law and the rated current (In) of 0.1A, that give you a resistance range of 10Ω max, 6.9Ω typical.
Considering that the voltage drop is at rated current and there may be some temperature effects that would raise the measured resistance, 3.0Ω sounds OK. If you're measuring this in-circuit, there may be something else contributing to the measurement, so be careful.


I measure it's resistance as 3 Ohm and I am not sure if it is OK or
not

According to the data sheet, 3 Ω seems a little low in value: -

The maximum resistance will be 10 Ω and the typical resistance will be 6.9 Ω. Image cropped from the datasheet.
